# How do I solve the error I get when creating a react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, vite

I have created a new React project with Vite. When I run the 'npm run dev' command, it hosts the project. When I open the project in the browser, I get the following error:

```
[plugin:vite:react-babel] Cannot redefine property: File
C:/Users/kaana/Desktop/tempfolio/tempfolio-react/src/main.jsx
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kaana\Desktop\tempfolio\tempfolio-react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kaana\Desktop\tempfolio\tempfolio-react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\helpers\config-api.js:16:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14
```

my main.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

How can i solve this error ?

I tried updating npm packages, Babel, and Vite, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling them. Still, the issue persists.

Comment: Could you update the code with the content of `src/main.jsx` ?

Comment: I updated the question by sharing the main.jsx file.

Comment: Think it should be `ReactDOM.render(...),document.getElementById('root')`.

Comment: Also what is your node version?

Comment: We need the content of the App.jsx file too.

Comment: My Node version is: v18.12.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the `node==20.6.0` then according to this post: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15927 that version has an issue that was patched some versions later you should install the version `node==20.11.0`.

In my case I got it working with the following instructions:

```bash
nvm install lts/iron # Which is the 20.11.0 version
nvm use 20.11.0
```

Depending on your configurations the process can be quite different, I had node installed with `brew` and needed to remove the brew version in order to get the nvm version working.

That solved my issue.